# CTRL + K, CTRL + F (Format Code) Not Working in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

The format selection command isn't working in SQL server management studio 2008 for me and I'm wondering if anyone might know how to get it working. I don't know if it was ever working.

Comment: Where is it documented that `Ctrl+K`, `Ctrl+F` even does this? Are you just basing it on your experience with visual studio? AFAIK there is no built in code formatting functionality in SSMS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have any add-ins installed? For me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> brings up the SSMS Tools Pack find dialog. So perhaps this is happening because an add-in has taken over the keyboard combo.

Also, what is your keyboard scheme under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard? If this has been switched to "SQL Server 2000" you might try switching it back to Standard.

Finally, I believe there are cases where the keyboard shortcuts can get messed up depending on the co-existence and order of install for Visual Studio / BIDS etc.

Comment: Does SSMS even have code formatting? I don't think it's based on Visual Studio like BIDS is.

Comment: That's possibly true, I think most folks use RedGate's tool or external tools for this. Unfortunately I don't have a "naked" version of SSMS anywhere without Mladen's SSMS Tools Pack installed, so I can't verify for sure what that keyboard combo does in a clean install...

Comment: I think @Rup is right, I just tried that keyboard combination on a "naked" version of SSMS and got the same message about command Format Selection not available. +1 for RedGate's tool

Comment: Gaah... Stupid microsoft! lol Are there any free tools like RedGate that do SQL formatting right inside SSMS?

Comment: @John RedGate has a tool but it isn't free - you'll need SQL Prompt 5.1 Pro - http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/features ; Mladen's tool also does some formatting but mostly around keywords - http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features ; there are certainly other tools out there but I'm not sure how many are free *and* can integrate into SSMS.

Comment: This has also just caught me out in SSMS2016 RC3. When I switched the environment back to Visual Studio 2010 compatible, all the keyboard shortcuts returned. I'm assuming a conflict with the underlying key bindings in VS2015 shell now used by SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 3):

IN SQL SERVER 2014

- First do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd>
- Then: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Can you add some context?

Comment: it Formating my query

Comment: This is the only answer that worked without any additional plugins or otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is really old, but for people searching for answers to this question I have this to add:

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key combination for format code comes from [poorsql.com](http://poorsql.com/).  They have a SSMS/Visual Studio plugin.  As of this date they currently support up to SSMS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't available on SQL Server Management Studio.

There are various add-on's you can use to do this. I personally use [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-refactor.aspx?gclid=CjwKCAjwq4fsBRBnEiwANTahcL_3cmIU0i2mKQRp6HJIqli0J-4ls5d8QaYOhVFgxPdrWOQtF-t7rhoCA0wQAvD_BwE). It gives you the option to create your own format template, so that your code is always easily readable for you.

Answer (score -3):

Check this link:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2413/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-part-1-of-2/

> ...You can select specific lines and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
>   followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment it out and
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
>   to uncomment it out...